# Open and install iOS app from UIwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, app-store

I have an apps link using link maker from AppStore . I have a `UIWebView` in my app and I am trying to load the link in `UIWebView` but each time I load that link it opens the inbuilt AppStore instead of showing the content in the `UIWebView`. I want to open the link in `UIWebView` instead of opening the inbuilt iOS AppStore.

This what i tried

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str];
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];

    // Here is the app id from itunesconnect
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@289382458", str];

   [webOpenApp loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
}

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
    if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the link to the question? if the link has HTML header that redirects to the App Store you can change the header if its your website. if its not there nothing you can do

Comment: can you please give me a sample on adding that HTML header.

Answer (score 1):

The `itms-apps://` is an special protocol that when iOS system read this it will launch the App Store to show that app. Apparently this is not what you want.

You should build the UI yourself to display the information of the app. And when user click the buy button you have to redirect user to App Store. Because App Store is the only place user could buy and download an app.

Comment: Instead of `itms-apps`, it's `itms-appss`. For example, itms-appss://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/yu-piao-er-dian-ying-yan-chu/id481589275?mt=8

Comment: @DawnSong, where do you find it should be `itms-appss`? All that I could find is use `itms-apps`.

Comment: When you open https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/wechat/id414478124?mt=8 in a WKWebView, it will navigate to such an url automatically.